# How to port forward 0ad game 20595

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I want to port forward 0ad as I cant join any game, it shows some errors.I don't know what to do as I'm a noob in port forwarding, please help me. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jcwV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZhed.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to port forward but dont know how to do clearly

Comment: After you've set up the port forwarding, you need to assign that IP to your computer otherwise it won't work. If your router has an option for port triggering that will allow you to set up the same concept, but it will dynamically open the ports when needed and close them when they are no longer needed.

Comment: Hi there Dr. Thanks for answering, can u please explain in detail about that assigning IP to computer again please

Comment: In your second screenshot, IP address 192.168.1.40 is the IP address that the port forwarding is being applied to. In order for it to work, you need to assign that exact IP address to the device that's needing the port forwarding. If you need further help, please do @DrZoo in your response so I get an inbox notification.